# Jackson cannot parse body of a POST request

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Spring Boot to implement two web services, User and Book, and I am implementing the POST methods. When I send a POST request, i include the hard-coded JSON object in the HTTP Body: I am working at the same time on the two services, and while the creation of the "user" object works fine, Jackson throws an exception for the Book class. This situation occurres also with Postman, so it is not a problem of the JSON creation.

This is the Book class

```
public class Book {
private String isbn, title, author, shipped;

public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, String shipped) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.shipped = shipped;
}

public Book(String isbn, String title, String author) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.shipped = "false";
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getShipped() {
    return shipped;
}

public void setShipped(String shipped) {
    this.shipped = shipped;
}
}
```

While this is the User one:

```
public class User {

private String emailAddress, name, surname;

public User(String emailAddress, String name, String surname) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

}
```

And these are the JSON objects in the body, printed when they are sent from the client
When I send a POST for creating a user, it's all good

```
{"emailAddress": "myname@mail.com","name":"MyName","surname": "MySurname"}
WS returns code 200
```

While for the book, the WS returns error 500

```
{"title": "MyTitle","author": "MyAuthor","shipped": "false","isbn": "1"}
WS returns code 500
```

And this exception is thrown

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.(...).entities.Book` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no d
elegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1615) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1077) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1332) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:331) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3521) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:378) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:342) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:186) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Book class you have 2 constructors meanwhile in User just has 1. Jackson might not know which constructors to invoke when deserializing your Book. Adding @JsonCreator annotation to your constructor might work.

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html

Comment: This was it. I can't tell how long I spent looking for a solution.